# Rally API get user stories not able to filter Schedule state

Tags: rally

The rally Api I used is unable to filter ScheduleState of type Accepted

> https://XXXX/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?find={"ScheduleState":"Accepted"}&fetch=ObjectID,FormattedID,ScheduleState,FlowStateChangedDate,InProgressDate,PlanEstimate,Blocked,BlockedReason,HasParent,Parent,RevisionHistory,Project&hydrate=["ScheduleState"]&pagesize=100

Can some one please help? how to get user stories that are accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be combining queries for the Web Services API and the Lookback API.  You will need to update this query to be:

> [https://XXXX/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query=(ScheduleState = Accepted )&fetch=ObjectID,FormattedID,ScheduleState,FlowStateChangedDate,InProgressDate,PlanEstimate,Blocked,BlockedReason,HasParent,Parent,RevisionHistory,Project&pagesize=100](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query=(%20ScheduleState%20=%20Accepted%20)&fetch=ObjectID,FormattedID,ScheduleState,FlowStateChangedDate,InProgressDate,PlanEstimate,Blocked,BlockedReason,HasParent,Parent,RevisionHistory,Project&pagesize-100)